# Vertical line in table is indented, but only when it is a command

Tags: tables, tabularx

I wanted to set up colored vertical lines in my table, while keeping horizontal lines black. This could easily be done by inserting `!{\color{green}\vline}` when a vertical line was needed. This worked as intended, as in this sample;

[image: table working as intended]

To cut down on typing, I made it into a command, but then the table got weird, moving the vertical lines a bit inwards;

[image: Table but with weird vertical lines]

I then made both tables within the same environment, but tables came out as above, despite running essentially the same code.

I was wondering what is causing it, so I can be aware of what other consequences it may have for my setup.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\gline{
{\color{green}\vline}
}

\begin{table}[p]
\centering
\begin{tabular} [b] {!{\gline}  l !{\gline} l !{\gline}}
\hline
htext1 & htext2 \\
text 1 & text2 \\
\end{tabular} \\
\vspace{1 cm}
\begin{tabular} [b] {!{\color{green}\vline}  l !{\color{green}\vline} l !{\color{green}\vline}}
\hline
htext1 & htext2 \\
text 1 & text2 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result of above code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your macro has spurious spaces around it, so the space is actually inside of your `!`. Note that if you omit `%` at the end of a line that'll add a space there (if TeX isn't in a mode in which it ignores spaces, for instance after a control sequence it'd be fine, as TeX ignores spaces following them).

So with your

```
\newcommand\gline{
{\color{green}\vline}
}
```

what you're actually getting from `!{\gline}` is

```
!{ {\color{green}\vline} }
```

To fix this, just put a `%` after `{` and `}` in the definition:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\newcommand\gline{%
{\color{green}\vline}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
\centering
\begin{tabular} [b] {!{\gline}  l !{\gline} l !{\gline}}
\hline
htext1 & htext2 \\
text 1 & text2 \\
\end{tabular} \\
\vspace{1 cm}
\begin{tabular} [b] {!{\color{green}\vline}  l !{\color{green}\vline} l !{\color{green}\vline}}
\hline
htext1 & htext2 \\
text 1 & text2 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Note that you can further reduce the amount of typing by defining `\gline` as a "column type" (obviously this isn't a column type, but that's the name of the interface provided by `array`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\newcolumntype\gline{!{{\color{green}\vline}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
\centering
\begin{tabular} [b] {\gline  l \gline l \gline}
\hline
htext1 & htext2 \\
text 1 & text2 \\
\end{tabular} \\
\vspace{1 cm}
\begin{tabular} [b] {!{\color{green}\vline}  l !{\color{green}\vline} l !{\color{green}\vline}}
\hline
htext1 & htext2 \\
text 1 & text2 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Result of both looks identical:

[image]

Comment: Yep, just tried it out, and that solved it! Thank you. It's the kind of thing that you just can forget to consider when focusing on learning a new tool. I had come across newcolumntype, but I think the naming, as you mentioned, had me convinced it wasn't "for that". I will give it a go. Much apprciated!

Comment: @Fibecker `\newcolumntype` basically defines a new accepted token in a `tabular`'s preamble and it'll get replaced by whatever you defined it as. A single token can be a character, or a single macro (note that conventionally most people use a character, not a macro name).